# Error RC1103 building opencv_contrib with Visual Stio 2017 opencv_core

Tags: opencv, build

I´m working in a project that uses the xfeatures2d module of open CV.
So im tyinging to build the contrib module. I'm following this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIpTks0G2m0

On Cmake on the files with the format BUILD_opencv_..... im only selecting 2 options BUILD_opencv_core & BUILD_opencv_xfeatures2d. If I select more modules I get more errors: 
link -> postimg.org/image/hn26hk8gh/

When I try to build the ALL_BUILD I get the following errors:
https://postimg.org/image/rvunndwi9/

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, it is better if you write the error you get instead of providing a link to it. Please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: This tutorial asks you to download opencv from a non-official source. Please download it from the official source at https://github.com/opencv/opencv.

Comment: @ShawnMathew That's exactly the same repo that the video talks about -- that's what it used to be named a year ago, and the link now redirects.

Comment: I´ve tried with the new/official release, but the problem persists :( https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/tag/3.2.0